# How to get IT resource Key from OIM using SQL query?

Tags: entitlements, identity-management, oim, identitymanager

To update child form lookup I need IT resource Key. Is there a SQL query for the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select ITRESOURCE_KEY from APP_INSTANCE where APP_INSTANCE_NAME ='<AppInstanceName>'
```

Answer (score 0):

It resources keys are stored in table of SVR.

```
SELECT * FROM SVR
```